# Replace all values in dataframe using another dataframe as key in R

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, dplyr, remap

I have two dataframes and I want to replace all values ( in all the columns) of df1 using the equivalent value in df2 (df2$value).

df1
[image]

```
structure(list(Cell_ID = c(7L, 2L, 3L, 10L), n_1 = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), n_2 = c(9L, 1L, 4L, 1L), n_3 = c(10L, 4L, 5L, 2L), n_4 = c(NA, 
5L, NA, 4L), n_5 = c(NA, 7L, NA, 6L), n_6 = c(NA, 9L, NA, 8L), 
    n_7 = c(NA, 10L, NA, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

df2
[image]

```
structure(list(Cell_ID = 0:10, value = c(5L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 
400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, 800L, 900L, 1000L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

The desired output would look like this:

[image]

So far I tried this as suggested in another similar post but its not doing it well (randomly missing some points)

```
key= df2$Cell_ID
value = df2$value
lapply(1:8,FUN = function(i){df1[df1 == key[i]] <<- value[i]})
```

[image]

**Note** that the numbers have been just multiplied by 10 for ease in the example the real data has numbers are all over the place so just multiplying the dataframe by 10 won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is `match` the elements with the 'Cell_ID' of second dataset and use that as index to return the corresponding 'value' from 'df2'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     mutate(across(everything(), ~  df2$value[match(., df2$Cell_ID)]))
```

-output

```
#  Cell_ID n_1 n_2  n_3 n_4 n_5 n_6  n_7
#1     700   5 900 1000  NA  NA  NA   NA
#2     200   5 100  400 500 700 900 1000
#3     300   5 400  500  NA  NA  NA   NA
#4    1000   5 100  200 400 600 800  300
```

---

Or another option is to use a named vector to do the match

```
library(tibble)
df1 %>%
      mutate(across(everything(), ~ deframe(df2)[as.character(.)]))
```

---

The `base R` equivalent is

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) df2$value[match(x, df2$Cell_ID)])
```

Comment: Thank you for this asnwer. This helpful.